# Dafny: How can I quantify over the "contents" of a codatatype?

Tags: dafny

Background: I am trying to write parser combinators in Dafny. This requires working on very long lists which I do not want to fully compute unless they are needed, so I am using an `IList` instead of a `seq` in order to simulate lazy evaluation. The problem which I am having is that I cannot find a way to express an equivalent to `forall x in sequence` when working with `ILists`.

I'm defining `IList` in the same way as Dafny's documentation and tests:

```
codatatype IList<T> = Nil | Cons(head: T, tail: IList<T>)
```

I want to define an `fmap` function over `IList`s which allows partial functions. Here is my initial (incorrect) implementation:

```
function method fmap<S, T>(list: IList<S>, fn: S --> T): IList<T>
{
  match list
  case Nil => Nil
  case Cons(s, rest) => Cons(fn(s), fmap(rest, fn))
}
```

This does not work, because the precondition to `fn` might not hold, and this is the root problem I'm trying to solve.

I tried to define a copredicate to express the concept of "forall" on infinite lists, and use that:

```
greatest predicate IListForall<T>(list: IList<T>, fn: T -> bool) {
  match list
  case Nil => true
  case Cons(head, rest) => fn(head) && IListForall(rest, fn)
}

function method fmap<S, T>(list: IList<S>, fn: S --> T): IList<T>
requires IListForall(list, fn.requires)
{ /* body unchanged */ }
```

This makes `fmap` verify, but when I try to use `fmap` I can't find a way to make this precondition satisfied. It comes up when I try to define a mapping function which works on lists containing a certain type:

```
datatype Container<T> = Container(value: T)

function method fmapContainers<T, U>(cs: IList<Container<T>>, fn: T -> U):
  IList<Container<U>>
{
  fmap(cs, (container: Container) => Container(fn(container.value)))
}
```

The invocation of `fmap` here gives me the error `possible violation of function precondition`. This doesn't seem right to me. `fn` is total, and so is the lambda that I'm passing to `fmap`, so I don't think there should be any precondition in play? I've attempted to write `fmapContainers` a few different ways with no success, which makes me think that I messed up from the beginning when I tried to express `forall` as a copredicate.

Is there a better way to express `forall` than what I did?

---

footnote: `fmapContainers` might sound useless, but it's the simplest form of my actual problem. To explain my motivation, here's the full implementation that I'm trying to get working:

```
datatype OneParse<T> = OneParse(parsed: T, remainder: string)
datatype Result<T> = Failure | Success(forest: IList<OneParse>)

type parser<T> = string -> Result<T>

function method fmapSuccess<S, T>(result: Result<S>, fn: S --> T): Result<T>
  requires result.Success?
  {
    Success(fmap(result.forest,
      (one: OneParse<S>) => OneParse(fn(one.parsed), one.remainder)))
  }

function method fmapParser<T, U>(p: parser<T>, fn: T --> U): parser<U> {
  s => var result := p(s); match result
      case Failure => Failure
      case Success(forest) => fmapSuccess(result, fn)
}
```

I think I can figure out how to make the full solution work on my own if someone provides tips for implementing `fmap` and `fmapContents`, so this is just for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is `greatest predicate` (`IListForall`) is not proved for function `(container: Container) => Container(fn(container.value))`. This is trivial to prove

```
greatest lemma IListForallLemma<T, U>(cs: IList<T>, fn: T -> U)
 ensures IListForall(cs, fn.requires)
{}
```

Now following code snippet verifies. I have made `fmapContainers` to `method` from `function method` to call above lemma.

```
codatatype IList<T> = Nil | Cons(head: T, tail: IList<T>)

greatest predicate IListForall<T>(list: IList<T>, fn: T -> bool)
{
  match list
  case Nil => true
  case Cons(head, rest) => fn(head) && IListForall(rest, fn)
}

function method fmap<S, T>(list: IList<S>, fn: S --> T): IList<T>
requires IListForall(list, fn.requires)
{
  match list
  case Nil => Nil
  case Cons(s, rest) => Cons(fn(s), fmap(rest, fn))
}

datatype Container<T> = Container(value: T)

greatest lemma IListForallLemma<T, U>(cs: IList<T>, fn: T -> U)
  ensures IListForall(cs, fn.requires)
{}

method fmapContainers<T, U>(cs: IList<Container<T>>, fn: T -> U) returns (r: IList<Container<U>>)
{
  IListForallLemma(cs, (container: Container) => Container(fn(container.value)));
  r := fmap(cs, (container: Container) => Container(fn(container.value)));
}
```

Comment: Testing on my own, I was able to do this while still keeping the function which invoked `IListForAllLemma` as `function method`

Comment: Right you can call lemma inside function method.